# Is an ungraded pass going to affect my PhD applications?

Tags: masters, application, gpa

Currently my MA gpa is a 70/100 and I'm studying in the UK. I just received the grade of my latest assignment, that is a 68. That means that my gpa is now bellow 70. However, the university is giving me the option of an ungraded pass for this assignment, so that my gpa will not be affected. If I select to apply for an ungraded pass, instead of a 68 in that assignment, are my future PhD applications going to be affected? I am concerned that an ungraded pass might not look good on my final record and in my PhD applications. Additionaly, I am still working on my dissertation, so if I achieve a high grade for it I can still improve my gpa. What do you think is the best course of action? Thank you!

Comment: Country? And what do those numbers mean? Aee they out of 100? And what is the best GPA?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I edited in the information. I'm studying in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

I have doubts that it will matter. The reasons for taking a pass might be obvious to a reader. Letting the numbers fall where they may might seem more honest.

But also consider that few (if any) programs will automatically exclude you for GPA alone. People are admitted into doctoral programs based on many things, none of which (other than dishonesty, perhaps) are determinative alone. People on an admissions committee will want to make a prediction about your likely success in the program and thereafter as well as your readiness to do research.

I also suspect that most committees will be a bit generous in the age of coronavirus, though that doesn't lessen the competition that every student faces. Make your best case for admission no matter which way you choose to jump on this (minor) issue.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is miniscule and it will not make a significant different in the average. I would suggest you kept the mark, which is considered rather high in UK standards. Having a first is meaningful for prestige reasons but a high 2.1 such is your is by no means damning - a 68 has no difference with a 70.